# Marching cubes?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, marching-cubes

I have an object made of points, lets say its point cloud, i want to render object from those points, i want object to look like those points were wrapped in a sheet of paper. I want to animate it, so first thing that came on my mind was marching cubes, but my object will not be a ball or cube, it will morph, is there any simpler approach than marching cubes?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking.  How would these objects morph?

Comment: This may help: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/greedy_projection.php "Fast triangulation of unordered point clouds"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "wrapped" a [3D convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms#Higher_dimensions) may produce the effect that you want.

Animate your vertices however you want and re-run the hull algorithm each time.

Comment: Marching cubes can certainly work.. it is in essence an algorithm that determines a 3D convex hull. As for animating, I have an instance running in javascript in webgl and even in javascript when I "dig" in my terrain it seems to animate pretty darn quik -> http://youtu.be/_oML6USPs20

Comment: marching cubes are used to generate the iso-surface of the object (given a static or dynamic threshold). It is not necessarily convex. It's not clear whether 'wrapped in a sheet of paper' means convex or not.

Answer (score 3):

The Marching Cubes algorithm seems like the best fit to what you're looking for -- not all point clouds are convex.  The algorithm may seem intimidating because of the large lookup table, but it is actually pretty straightforward. I have posted an example (using Three.js) at:

http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Marching-Cubes.html

Answer (score -1):

This seems like what you're looking for:
http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=25